# How to build a fluid gallery with bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3, gallery

I want build a gallery with bootstrap 3, I´m using the class .container-fluid for a full-width layout.

And I comment the padding-right and padding-left columns in the file bootstrap.css:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
 /* padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;*/
}
```

This is the result:
[image: SCREENSHOT]

**But I want to make this(image photoshopped):**
[image: SCREENSHOT]

This is my layout code:

```
<!--PHOTOS CONTAINER -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<!--FIRST ROW-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<img src="img/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<img src="img/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<img src="img/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<img src="img/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
</div>

</div>

<!--SECOND ROW-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<img src="img/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<img src="img/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<img src="img/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
<img src="img/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive"> 
</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a jQuery plugin like Masonry or Isotope..

http://www.bootply.com/106140

Another way is using CSS 3 column-width..

http://www.bootply.com/122476